# Custom messages for SpringBoot RESTful bean validation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I added a validation (`@javax.validation.Valid`) to my `@RestController` and in the `@RequestBody` class I used `@NotEmpty` annotation:

```
public class Invoice {

    @NotEmpty
    private String commentText;

    // omitted
}
```

When a REST call with missing `commentText` is invoked the proper error is returned to the client:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1475599494823,
   "status": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
   "errors": [   {
      "codes":       [
         "NotEmpty.invoice.commentText",
         "NotEmpty.commentText",
         "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
         "NotEmpty"
      ],
      "arguments": [      {
         "codes":          [
            "invoice.commentText",
            "commentText"
         ],
         "defaultMessage": "commentText",
         "code": "commentText"
      }],
      "defaultMessage": "may not be empty",
      "objectName": "invoice",
      "field": "commentText",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "NotEmpty"
   }],
   "message": "Validation failed for object='invoice'. Error count: 1",
   "path": "/api/invoices/1"
}
```

Then I have created **src/main/resources/messages.properties** with the following content:

```
NotEmpty.invoice.commentText=Please type a comment
```

**The problem is** that instead of the custom ‘Please type a comment’ the original error message is returned to the client.

I am using SpringBoot 1.4 with YAML configuration and running the application in Eclipse.

Any idea where the issue might be?

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@NotEmpty`annotation try to use alternative from `javax.validation` package: `@NotNull` and `@Size(min=1)`.
Also you may find this sample project useful for you: https://github.com/MichaelKnight/ValidandoFormularios

If for some reason you need to use @NotEmpty annotations, then you should create a file ValidationMessages.properties and place it into your classpath.

To avoid problems with key translation you may indicate message key like this: `@NotEmpty(message="{NotEmpty.invoice.commentText}")`. Or have a look here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation

Comment: I tried `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` with `NotNull.unidentifiedInvoice.commentText=Please type a comment` in `messages.properties` but it still returns the default `"defaultMessage": "may not be null"`

Comment: Have you changed class name to UnidentifiedInvoice? If not try to use this key: `NotNull.invoice.commentText`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did...that is however not the root cause of the issue.